# Finding a point from a set of contours such that it is nearest to a given point

Tags: plotting, mathematical-optimization

I have several contour lines and one point. How can I find a point in one of those contour lines which is nearest to the given point?

```
(*Create the implicit curves*)
Data={{10,20,1},{10,40,2},{10,60,3},{10,80,4},{20,25,2},{20,45,3},{20,65,4},{30,30,3},{30,50,4},{40,35,4},{40,55,5},{50,20,4},{50,40,5},{60,25,5}};
U=NonlinearModelFit[Data,a x^b (y^(1-b))+c,{a,b,c},{x,y}];
L={ContourPlot[U[x,y]=={1},{x,0,100},{y,0,100},ContourStyle->Red],ContourPlot[U[x,y]=={2},{x,0,100},{y,0,100},ContourStyle->Magenta],ContourPlot[U[x,y]=={3},{x,0,100},{y,0,100},ContourStyle->Brown],ContourPlot[U[x,y]=={4},{x,0,100},{y,0,100},ContourStyle->Blue],ContourPlot[U[x,y]=={5},{x,0,100},{y,0,100},ContourStyle->Green]};
(*Point nearest to which we need to find the points on the curves*)
pt={30,50};
(*Graphic*)
Show[L,Graphics[{PointSize[Large],Blue,Point[pt]}],FrameLabel->{"X","Y"}]
```

[image]

Comment: Did you try FindMinimum?

Comment: @ Michael E2, noted and added.

Comment: Would it be possible to approach this by looking for intersections of a circle (centered at `pt`, with variable radius) with each of the curves? As radius decreases, the circle would intersect with fewer curves, eventually only intersecting one of them.  As it shrinks further, the pair of intersections with that curve will become a single point, the closest point to the center of the circle.  (Apologies if this is naive.)

Comment: @c_susetyo I deleted the end part of your question containing my old code as I just adapted my answer to your updated question.

Answer (score 15):

For a general purpose & more accurate solution I can suggest the following.

**Update**(the missing `data` part)

```
(* Create the implicit curves analytically *)
conts = ((a x^b  (y^(1 - b)) + c /. U["BestFitParameters"]) == #) & /@Range[5];
(* Given x val function to find y=f(x) values per curve *)
fun[exp_] := {#,y /. Quiet@FindRoot[Evaluate@(exp /. x -> #), {y, 1}]} &;
(* Find discrete (x,f(x)) for 0<x<100 *)
data = (fun[#] /@ Range[.1, 101, .25]) & /@ conts;
```

Continuing the old code

```
(* Interpolate the data *)
    ints = Interpolation /@ data;
    (* Given a point or a list of points following function finds the minimizer
    (x,f(x)) on each curve *)
    xpts[pt_] := With[{int = #},
    NMinimize[{Evaluate@Total[Sqrt[(x - #1)^2 + (int[x] - #2)^2] &@@@ pt], .1 <x<100},
    {x}]] & /@ ints;
    {#2[[2]], #3[#2[[2]]]} & @@ Flatten@First@Sort@Transpose@{xpts[pt], ints}
```

> {36.9385, 52.1471}

For fun lets allow some dynamics! Note that I did not update the animations here. The code is self-contained now so one can reproduce similar things easily.

[image]

**Note:**

The above function is written in such a way that one can have more than one point say $X=(x_1,...,x_n)$. Then it will find the unique minimizer $P=(a,b)$ on the given contours such that $dist=\sum_{i=1}^{n}d(P,x_i)$ is minimized where $d(*,*)$ is the Euclidean distance metric. Such a case follows in the figure. Such an example follows below. Here the number or points $\#(X)=n$ is increasing at every step of the animation. They are the black dots on the plot.

One should also note given a large number of points one can try `FindMinimum` in place of `NMinimize` but for up to 500 points `NMinimize` seems to do the job well enough.

[image]

**Code:**

```
xptsSum[pt_] := 
 With[{int = #}, 
    x /. Last@
      NMinimize[{Evaluate@
         Total[Sqrt[(x - #1)^2 + (int[x] - #2)^2] & @@@ pt], .1 < x < 
         100}, {x}]] & /@ ints; CptSum = 
 Table[{50 + Sin[u^.6] u , 40 - Cos[u^.4] u}, {u, 0, 50, 50./89}];
clus = Take[CptSum, #] & /@ Range[Length@CptSum];
imsSum = ParallelMap[With[{pt = #},
     xVals = xptsSum[pt];
     Plot[Evaluate[(#[x]) & /@ ints], {x, .1, 100}, 
      PlotRange -> {{0, 100}, {-10, 110}}, Frame -> True, 
      AspectRatio -> 1, ImageSize -> 500, 
      Epilog -> {{Directive[Opacity[.7], Gray], 
         Line[pt]}, {Directive[Opacity[.7], Black], PointSize@Small, 
         Point /@ pt}, {Red, PointSize@Large, 
         MapThread[Point@{#2, #1[#2]} &, {ints, xVals}]}}]] &, clus];
ListAnimate[imsSum, DefaultDuration -> 10]
```

Comment: (+1)You just achieved ultimate coolness!

Comment: Sometimes, `Norm` can be faster than `Sqrt[x^2+y^2...]`.

Comment: I put together this answer and my data. It works very well. Great job, PlatoManiac.

Answer (score 8):

One way you could try is to examine the points of the plot. If `cp` is the plot:

```
points = Cases[cp, {x_?NumericQ, y_?NumericQ} :> {x, y}, Infinity];
nearest = Last@Nearest[points, First[pt], 2]
```

> ```
> {36.7666, 51.0523}
> ```

This is not the nearest point to `pt` - that's `pt` itself - but the next nearest:

```
Show[
 cp,
 Graphics[{Red, Disk[nearest]}]
 ]
```

[image: plot]

As yves points out in the comments, this only works as well as the original plot allows:

[image: blow up]

so technically I haven't found the nearest possible point, just the nearest sampled point.

Comment: Nice and concise. The only thing to be aware of is that this entirely depends on the discrete sampling of the contour lines by `Plot` (and associated options).

Comment: @yves good point, I'll add a note.

Comment: @cormullion very nice visual treat!

Comment: @PlatoManiac Well, not as cool as another answer here...! :)

Answer (score 3):

My original idea was the same as [cormullion's](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/61/cormullion), and then followed by `FindMinimum`.  But here another, still related way using `MeshFunctions`.  It's not as efficient in general as other ways, perhaps, but as a method, it is sometimes convenient.

The idea is to create a mesh function that has the same sign as the angle between the vector from the `pt` to the curve and the normal to the curve.  Then use `Mesh` to include the points where the angle is zero (thereby overcoming the limitation on cormullion's `ContourPlot`/`Nearest` method).  To avoid including the mesh points in `Nearest`, I set `MeshStyle -> None`. The mesh is still computed, I have to select those points that are on the contours.  These appear in `Lines`.

```
clevels = {3, 6, 9, 12, 15, 18, 24, 35};
test[a_, b_, c_] = a x^b (y^(1 - b)) + c;
meshfn = Numerator @ Together[
           Cross[(pt - {x, y})].D[Rationalize@test[.42, .55, .1], {{x, y}}]]
plot = ContourPlot[Evaluate@test[.42, .55, .1],
   {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100},
   Contours -> clevels, 
   ContourStyle -> ColorData[1] /@ Range@Length@clevels, 
   ContourShading -> None,
   Mesh -> {{0}}, MeshStyle -> None,
   MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[meshfn]]}];
cpts = First @ Cases[plot,
                     GraphicsComplex[pts_, __] :>
                       pts[[Flatten @ Cases[plot, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity]]],
                     Infinity];
nf = Nearest @ cpts;

Show[
 plot,
 Graphics[{Blue, PointSize@Large, Point@pt, Red, Point@nf[pt]}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can make a nice plot by including the mesh line.

```
nf2 = Nearest[Function[{x, y}, Evaluate[meshfn]] @@@ cpts -> cpts];
ContourPlot[Evaluate@test[.42, .55, .1],
 {x, 0, 100}, {y, 0, 100},
 Contours -> clevels, 
 ContourStyle -> ColorData[1] /@ Range @ Length @ clevels, 
 ContourShading -> None,
 Mesh -> {{0}},
 MeshFunctions -> {Function[{x, y, z}, Evaluate[meshfn]]},
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[Large], Point@pt, PointSize[Medium], 
   Thin, {Point[#], Line[{pt, #} & /@ #]} &@
    nf2[0., 2 + Length @ clevels]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

I combined my data and answer from PlatoManiac, as follows;

```
(*Input Data*)
Data={{10,20,1},{10,40,2},{10,60,3},{10,80,4},{20,25,2},{20,45,3},{20,65,4},{30,30,3},{30,50,4},{40,35,4},{40,55,5},{50,20,4},{50,40,5},{60,25,5}};
U = NonlinearModelFit[Data, a x^b (y^(1 - b)) + c, {a, b, c}, {x, y}];
(*Create the implicit curves analytically*)
conts=(U[x,y]==#==#)&/@{1,2,3,4,5};
(*Given x val following function finds y=f(x) values per curve*)
fun[exp_]:={#,y/.Quiet@FindRoot[Evaluate@(exp/.x->#),{y,1}]}&;
(*Find discrete (x,f(x)) for 0<x<100*)
data=(fun[#]/@Range[.1,101,10])&/@conts;
(*point closest to which we need to find the points on the curves*)
pt={{34,52}};
(*Interpolate the data*)
ints=Interpolation/@data;
(*Given a point or a list of points following function finds the minimizer (x,f(x)) on each curve*)
xpts[pt_]:=With[{int=#},NMinimize[{Evaluate@Total[Sqrt[(x-#1)^2+(int[x]-#2)^2]&@@@pt],.1<x<100},{x}]]&/@ints;
{#2[[2]],#3[#2[[2]]]}&@@Flatten@First@Sort@Transpose@{xpts[pt],ints}
{35.9226, 53.3513}
```

The result can be evaluated in code;

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate@conts,{x,0,100},{y,0,100},ContourStyle->{Red,Magenta,Brown,Blue,Green},FrameLabel->{"X","Y"},Epilog->{{Blue,PointSize@Large,Point[pt]},{Red,PointSize@Large,Point[{35.9226,53.3513}]}}]
```

[image]

Thank you all for your answers.