# HarmonicNumber problem

Tags: equation-solving, complex, special-functions

I am looking for all the roots of [`HarmonicNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/HarmonicNumber.html), in the domain [-30, 1] and [0, 6000] for the real and imaginary parts, respectively, and where the parameter `n` of `HarmonicNumber` is as high as 200.

This problem had been asked before in [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/43758/plotting-zeros-of-a-complex-variable).

As I increase the size of the domains where I am looking for roots, the following warnings show up:

> FindRoot::jsing: "Encountered a singular Jacobian at the point {x,y} = {56.9935,171.987}. Try perturbing the initial point(s)."
>
> FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances "

Could you help me fix this? Or suggest another way to solve this equation.

I got the same warnings when I tried to apply another technique as described in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/275/updating-wagons-findallcrossings2d-function/713#713)

Here is the code:

```
Options[FindRoots2D] = {PlotPoints -> Automatic, MaxRecursion -> Automatic}; 

FindRoots2D[funcs_, {x_, a_, b_}, {y_, c_, d_}, opts___] := Module[
{fZero, seeds, signs, fy},fy = Compile[{x, y}, Evaluate[funcs[[2]]]]; 
fZero = Cases[Normal[
 ContourPlot[
    funcs[[1]] == 0, 
    {x, a-(b-a)/97, b+(b-a)/103}, {y, c-(d-c)/98, d+(d-c)/102}, 
    Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ContourPlot]]]]], 
 Line[z_] :> z, Infinity]; 

 seeds = Flatten[(
 (signs = Sign[Apply[fy, #1, {1}]]; 
  #1[[1 + Flatten[Position[Rest[signs*RotateRight[signs]], -1]]]]) &
 ) /@ fZero, 1];
 If[seeds == {}, {}, 
 Select[
    Union[({x, y} /.
       FindRoot[{funcs[[1]], funcs[[2]]}, {x, #1[[1]]}, {y, #1[[2]]}, 
          Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[FindRoot]]]] & ) /@ seeds, 
       SameTest -> (Norm[#1 - #2] < 10^(-6) & )], 
    a <= #1[[1]] <= b && c <= #1[[2]] <= d & ]]]
n = 20;
zeros = FindRoots2D[{Re[HarmonicNumber[n, x + I y]], Im[HarmonicNumber[n, x + I y]]}, {x, -30, 1}, {y, 0, 6000}]
mediumSeaGreen = RGBColor[0.235298`, 0.702002`, 0.443098`];
violet = RGBColor[0.559999`, 0.370006`, 0.599994`];
orangeRed = RGBColor[1.`, 0.270608`, 0.`];
ContourPlot[{Re[HarmonicNumber[n, x + I y]] == 0, Im[HarmonicNumber[n, x + I y]] == 0}, 
{x, -30, 1}, {y, 0, 6000},
MaxRecursion -> 3,ContourStyle -> {Directive[Thick, mediumSeaGreen],
Directive[Thick, violet]}, 
Epilog -> {PointSize[0.02], orangeRed, Point[zeros]}]
```

The following was my trial of n=20 and range x={-32,1} and y={0,4000}.

```
n = 20;
seeds = findSeeds[myHN[n, x + I y], {x, -32, 1}, {y, 0,   4000}, 
PlotPoints -> 25, 
MeshFunctions -> {myHNReImCx[n][#1, #2] &, 
  myHNReImCy[n][#1, #2] &}]; // AbsoluteTiming
allfoundzeros = 
Quiet@myFRC[myHN[n, z], {z, -32, 1 + 4000 I}, 
 seeds.{1, I}]; // AbsoluteTiming
 uniqueszeros = #[[First@Ordering[Abs@myHN[n, #]]]] & /@ 
 findclusters[allfoundzeros, 10.^-6]; // AbsoluteTiming
   zeros = Pick[uniqueszeros, 
 With[{zz = Developer`ToPackedArray@N@uniqueszeros}, 
 UnitStep[(#1 - (-32)) (1 - #1) (#2) (4000 - #2)] &[Re[zz], 
  Im[zz], 1]], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
 Length[zeros]
 zeroplot = 
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.0035], Red, 
 Point@Transpose@{Re[zeros], Im[zeros]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-32, 1}, {0, 4000}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]
```

Comment: Post your code please.

Comment: I ask you in all earnestness: do you think anybody can help you when don't show the code you have written.

Comment: I have updated the code.

Comment: Oh. No problem. Thanks for your reply. Enjoy your vacation.

Comment: See related posts [Triangular numbers boolean function](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/54649/triangular-numbers-boolean-function/54660#54660), [When does the real part of Zeta vanish?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34604/when-does-the-real-part-of-zeta-vanish-on-the-critical-line/34607#34607), [Double series over primes](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32513/double-series-over-primes/32529#32529), and [Why do these zetas...](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/25430/why-do-these-two-different-zetas-produce-the-same-value/25439#25439)

Answer (score 7):

The problems with the method seems to arise from two sources, the objective function (and its components `Re`, `Im`, `HarmonicNumber`) and the working precision (`MachinePrecision`).

**The objective function**

*The Jacobian*: The functions `Re` and `Im` do not have derivatives.  Inspecting the Jacobian at `{56.9935, 171.987}` shows unevaluated derivatives:

```
D[{Re[HarmonicNumber[n, x + I y]], Im[HarmonicNumber[n, x + I y]]}, {{x, y}}] /.
  Thread[{x, y} -> {56.9935, 171.987}]
((* {{(-4.7632*10^-18 - 8.08894*10^-19 I) Derivative[1][Re][1. + 1.16699*10^-18 I],... *)
```

The derivatives of `HarmonicNumber` evaluate to a complex number but the derivatives of `Re` and `Im` do not.  In such a case, I believe `FindRoot` will use a finite difference method for computing the Jacobian.  **Insufficient working precision** can lead to issues in computing the Jacobian, which is not the hint provided by `FindRoot::jsing` message.  In particular, function evaluations that mathematically should produce distinct numbers might be equal at `MachinePrecision` and cancel out.

*Precision*: Mathematically, `HarmonicNumber[n, z]` and `Sum[1/k^z, {k, n}]` are equivalent.   One would like to think that `HarmonicNumber` would be at least as precise and fast as the sum.  This may be true over some domains.  For small values of `n` (certainly up to `200` and more), the sum is more precise. In fact, over the domain of this problem (`n <= 200`, `z` in the complex rectangle from `-30 + 0 I` to `1 + 6000 I`), the sum is much more precise.  For `n = 20` and 1000 random, arbitrary-precision complex numbers with precision [`$MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/$MachinePrecision.html) (15.95), the mean loss of precision for the sum was 4.3 digits and for `HarmonicSum`, it was 14.1 digits.  For `n = 20` and 1000 random, arbitrary-precision complex numbers with precision `100`, the mean loss of precision for the sum was 4.3 digits and for `HarmonicSum`, it was 26.6 digits.

*Speed*:  The sum is also considerable faster than `HarmonicNumber` for small values of `n`.  At about `n == 1800`, the speed of the sum and `HarmonicNumber` are about equal; for larger values of `n`, `HarmonicNumber` is faster.

*Compilability*: `HarmonicNumber` is not compilable.  This is not a serious problem, but the `FindRoots2D` code compiles the objective functions.

**Working precision**

[`MachinePrecision`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/MachinePrecision.html) is good enough for many cases, but numerical errors can accumulate and (1) cause a Jacobian computed with finite differences to vanish erroneously or (2) confuse the root-finding algorithm with erratic function evaluations.  These seem to be happening in this case.  The first may be the reason for the `FindRoot::jsing` error; the second may be the reason for the `FindRoot::lstol` warning.  For a function with isolated critical points, a `FindRoot::jsing` ought to be rare.  A `FindRoot::lstol` warning can happen when `FindRoot` gets stuck near a local extremum, but I was not able to find such an example in the OP's problem after a (very) brief search.

#### Some improvements

**Increase `WorkingPrecision`**

Setting `WorkingPrecision -> 100` took care of the `FindRoot::jsing` errors.  It did not take care of all the `FindRoot::lstol` warnings. However, it is much slower to use arbitrary-precision arithmetic on all solutions.

**Use the explicit sum instead `HarmonicNumber`**

As described above, using an explicit sum (or `Plus`) expression results in greater accuracy and speed.  Below `myHN` is my version of `HarmonicNumber`.   If real and imaginary parts are desired, then `myHNReIm` can be used.  It can be compiled, which will result in much faster computations at `MachinePrecision`.  (For a specific integer `n`, each definition generates the sum to be computed and memoizes it.  In this way the `Sum` is expanded only once.)

```
myHN[n_Integer, z0_] := Block[{z},                  (* complex-valued *)
   myHN[n, z_] := Evaluate@Sum[1/k^z, {k, n}];
   myHN[n, z0]
   ];
myHNReIm[n_Integer, x0_, y0_] :=                    (* real and imaginary parts *)
  Block[{x, y, k}, 
   With[{reHN = Simplify[Re[1/k^(x + I y)] // ComplexExpand, 
       x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals && k > 0], 
     imHN = Simplify[Im[1/k^(x + I y)] // ComplexExpand, 
       x ∈ Reals && y ∈ Reals && k > 0]},
    myHNReIm[n, x_, y_] := Evaluate@{Sum[reHN, {k, n}], Sum[imHN, {k, n}]};
    myHNReIm[n, x0, y0]
    ]];
myHNReImCx[n_Integer] :=                            (* real part, compiled *)
  myHNReImCx[n] = 
   Compile @@ Hold[{x, y}, Evaluate@First@myHNReIm[n, x, y]];
myHNReImCy[n_Integer] :=                            (* imaginary part, compiled *)
  myHNReImCy[n] = 
   Compile @@ Hold[{x, y}, Evaluate@Last@myHNReIm[n, x, y]];
myHNReImC[n_Integer, x_?NumericQ,  y_?NumericQ] :=  (* interface to compiled parts *)
  {myHNReImCx[20][x, y], myHNReImCy[20][x, y]};
```

**Use the complex-valued function**

Using `myHN`, which returns complex values is faster than using the individual components (such as in `myHNReIm`).  This is true for `HarmonicNumber`, too.  First of all, `FindRoot` can deal with such functions. For either `myHN` or `HarmonicNumber`, the Jacobian can be computed symbolically, which helps `FindRoot` to be efficient.  And the way the real and imaginary parts are used in the call to `FindRoots2D`, the harmonic number has to be computed twice for each input.

**Use `Check` to catch troublesome seeds**

One can use `Check` to catch error/warning messages and re-execute `FindRoot` with adjusted settings.  The following catches singular Jacobians, line-step tolerance warnings, and nonconvergence after the maximum number of interations and restarts `FindRoot` with a higher working precision.  If messages are generated on the second try, an empty solution `{}` is returned on the assumption that a zero is not going to be found near the seed (starting point) `x0`.  One could instead store them in some other variable and inspect them later.  They might correspond to an actual root.

```
Check[{sol = FindRoot[f, {x, x0}]
 Check[FindRoot[f, {x, x /. sol}, WorkingPrecision -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 8],
  {}],
 {FindRoot::jsing, FindRoot::lstol, FindRoot::cvmit}]
```

Whether to restart `FindRoot` where it stopped `x /. sol` or from the initial starting point `x0` is open to debate.  If the solution `sol` is closer to the true zero, it will save some time.  If round-off error has moved the solution far away from the true zero, the zero may be missed.  In the OP's case, it seems best to start at the original seed (see below).

**Use `MeshFunctions` to look for seed points**

The following an arguable improvement.  One can use `ContourPlot` in the form

```
ContourPlot[f1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, MeshFunctions -> {f2}, Mesh -> {{0}}]
```

to find the seed points, which [I've used before](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/34282) (see also [1](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/10475), [2](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/36948)).  Here `f2` needs to be a pure function; it also ought to be continuous for good behavior.  `ContourPlot` takes time and adding mesh functions increases the time it takes.  It actually will search for the point on the contour line where `f2 == 0`.

**Use the real and imaginary parts both ways in `ContourPlot`**

Using one `ContourPlot` of the real part and searching every contour line for a change in sign of the imaginary part, as in `FindRoots2D`, is generally a good way to find zeros.  One could also switch the roles of the real and imaginary parts.  It turns out, more zeros are discovered if you do both.  Since `ContourPlot` takes time, both plots could be computed in parallel, which won't take any more real time, if you have at least two cores.

**Avoid `Union`**

Unless you need the zeros sorted, `Union` tends to be slow.  Here is a way to delete repeated roots that has two advantages, it is a bit faster and you can pick the root that gives the smallest value of `HarmonicNumber`.  While `HarmonicNumber` is rather oscillatory, this probably gives the root closest to the actual zero.  The function `findClusters` gathers, for each data point, the data points within a certain radius and then deletes the duplicate clusters:

```
findclusters[data_, r_: 10^-12] := With[{nf = Nearest[data]},
   DeleteDuplicates[Sort[nf[#, {All, (* use Length[data] instead of All for pre-V10 *)
                                r}]] & /@ data]
   ];
```

One can then select the member of each cluster that produces the smallest function value like this:

```
reducedzeros = #[[First@Ordering[Abs @ myHN[20, #]]]] & /@ findclusters[zeros, 10^-6]
```

Overall this was about 6 times faster than `Union` on 27000 zeros.

**Stopping runaway roots**

If we use `FindRoot` like this

```
FindRoot[f, {z, seed, -30 + 0. I, 1 + 6000 I}]
```

we can catch the message `FindRoot::reged` with `Check`.  This message indicates that the search for the root has left the region.  If the region is slightly larger than `{-30 + 0. I, 1 + 6000 I}`, then perhaps such a seed can be safely discarded.  It saves a lot of time, since `FindRoot` will pursue a root well beyond the region of interest.

**Parallelize**

There are a few things that can be parallelized, and since multi-core machines are now common, it makes sense to do so.  This is particularly so for the `FindRoot` calls on the thousands of seeds.

#### Some code

I'll separate `FindRoots2D` into two parts, finding the initial seeds and finding the zeros.

```
Clear[findSeeds];
findSeeds[f_, {x_, a_, b_}, {y_, c_, d_}, opts : OptionsPattern[ContourPlot]] :=
 Module[{plotf, mf1, mf2},
  plotf = Function @@ Hold[{x, y}, Evaluate@f];
  If[OptionValue[MeshFunctions] === {},
   {mf1, mf2} = {
     With[{mf = 
        Compile[{x0, y0}, Evaluate[Re[f] /. {x -> x0, y -> y0}]]}, 
      mf[##] &],
     With[{mf = 
        Compile[{x0, y0}, Evaluate[Im[f] /. {x -> x0, y -> y0}]]}, 
      mf[##] &]
     },
   {mf1, mf2} = OptionValue[MeshFunctions]
   ];
  Join @@ Parallelize[
    {Cases[Normal@#, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity] &[
      ContourPlot[
       Re @ f == 0,
       {x, a - (b - a)/97, b + (b - a)/103}, {y, c - (d - c)/98, d + (d - c)/102},
       ContourStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {mf2}, Mesh -> {{0}}, opts]
      ],
     Cases[Normal@#, Point[p_] :> p, Infinity] &[
      ContourPlot[
       Im @ f == 0,
       {x, a - (b - a)/97, b + (b - a)/103}, {y, c - (d - c)/98, d + (d - c)/102},
       ContourStyle -> None, MeshFunctions -> {mf1}, Mesh -> {{0}}, opts]
      ]}
    ]
  ]
```

The tolerance to reject a seed as a nonroot is set at 10^-6.  This could be changed or made an option.  It appears in two places.

```
Clear[myFRC];
myFRC[f_, {z_, a_, b_}, seeds_, opts___] := Module[{z1, z2},
  z1 = Re[a - (b - a)/97] + Im[a - (b - a)/98] I; 
  z2 = Re[b + (b - a)/103] + Im[b + (b - a)/102] I;
  z /. Flatten[
    ParallelMap[
     Module[{sol},
       Quiet[       (* did not suppress FindRoot::jsing *)
        Check[      (* for FindRoot::reged : no solution *)
         Check[{    (* for FindRoot::jsing, FindRoot::lstol, FindRoot::cvmit : restart *)
          sol = FindRoot[f, {z, #1, z1, z2}, 
             Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[FindRoot]]]]},
          Check[    (* for any message : no solution *)
           If[Abs[f /. sol] < 10^-6,   (* tolerance 10^-6 for nonzero *)
            {sol},
            If[Abs[f /. #] < 10^-6, {#}, {}] &@
             FindRoot[f, {z, SetPrecision[#1, 100], z1, z2},
              WorkingPrecision -> 100, AccuracyGoal -> 8, 
              Evaluate[FilterRules[{opts}, Options[FindRoot]]]]],
           {}],
          {FindRoot::jsing, FindRoot::lstol, FindRoot::cvmit}],
         {}, {FindRoot::reged}],
        {FindRoot::reged, FindRoot::lstol, FindRoot::cvmit}
        ]
       ] &,
     seeds
     ],
    1]
  ]
```

**Example**

The steps in this example could replace the body of the code for `FindRoots2D`, if desired.

I used [`Pick`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Pick.html) with [`UnitStep`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitStep.html) instead of `Select`.  In this case it is about ten times faster.  Packing the array (`` Developer`ToPackedArray@N@... `` makes only a little difference, on my machine); there is also a small time savings from reducing the arbitrary precision zeros to `MachinePrecision`, whether the list is packed or not.

```
n = 20;
seeds = findSeeds[myHN[n, x + I y], {x, -30, 1}, {y, 0, 6000},
    PlotPoints -> 25,
    MeshFunctions -> {myHNReImCx[n][#1, #2] &,
      myHNReImCy[n][#1, #2] &}]; // AbsoluteTiming
allfoundzeros = 
   Quiet @ myFRC[myHN[n, z], {z, -30, 1 + 6000 I}, 
     seeds.{1, I}]; // AbsoluteTiming
uniqueszeros = #[[First @ Ordering[Abs @ myHN[20, #]]]] & /@ 
    findclusters[allfoundzeros, 10^-6]; // AbsoluteTiming
zeros = Pick[
    uniqueszeros,
    With[{zz = Developer`ToPackedArray @ N @ uniqueszeros},
      UnitStep[(#1 - (-30)) (1 - #1) #2 (6000 - #2)] &[Re[zz], Im[zz], 1]],
    1]; // AbsoluteTiming
Length[zeros]
zeroplot = Graphics[{PointSize[Tiny], Red, Point @ Transpose@{Re[zeros], Im[zeros]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-30, 1}, {0, 6000}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]

(*
  {8.560900, Null}
  {32.787730, Null}
  {1.368914, Null}
  {0.011737, Null}
  {0.000582, Null}
  2429
*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Verification:

```
myHN[n, zeros] // Abs // Max
(* 5.11995*10^-7 *)
```

#### Caveat

Being sure you have found all the zeros seems problematic.  Changing the `PlotPoints` option gave different numbers of seeds and zeros.  There seem to be about ten times as many seeds generated as zeros, which strikes me as a very poor ratio.  Increasing the `WorkingPrecision` on `ContourPlot` did not change the result.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time on my problem. I just get back to school, so I did not know your update.

Comment: @user16023 You're quite welcome.  No worries about the delay.

Comment: I could not have a chance to run you code until today. Unfortunately, I can not get the plot as you did. I check the code carefully and confuse that where the "foundzeros" in the example code came from. I guess it would be "allfoundzeros". But the code still does not excute. Could you give me some advices or post the entire code that produced your plot? Thank you very much. Have a nice day.

Comment: @user16023 See if it works now.  Aside from changing the variable names, I must have had a `findSeeds` defined for complex `z` in *Mma* as well as the one posted for `x + I y`.  Hopefully the update makes everything consistent.  Worked when I copy-pasted it just now.

Comment: Yes. It works now. My slow computer takes roughly 30mins to run the code. But I am happy to see the plot showing up. And it has only one warning, "Nearest::near3: {All,1/1000000} is neither a non-negative integer nor a list of the form {n, r} with n a positive integer and r a non-negative real number. >> , and General::stop: Further output of Nearest::near3 will be suppressed during this calculation. >> ". I really appreciate if you could give me a hint to fix this warning as well. Thanks again and have a good one.

Comment: @user16023 Try this definition: `findclusters[data_, r_: 10^-12] := With[{nf = Nearest[data]}, DeleteDuplicates[Sort[nf[#, {Length[data], r}]] & /@ data]]`  The keyword `All` must not be recognized by `Nearest` until V10.

Comment: I update the code as you suggested and there is a similar warning, " Nearest::near3: "{8216,1/1000000} is neither a non-negative integer nor a list of the form {n, r} with n a positive integer and r a non-negative real number." " I am sorry to bother you. You can reply whenever you are free. Have a good night.

Comment: @user16023 Well, "{8216, 1/1000000}" is a "a list of the form {n, r} with n a positive integer and r a non-negative real number." Maybe *M* wants 1/1000000 to be type `Real` -- try `findclusters[allfoundzeros, 1.*10^-6]`.  (What version of *Mathematica* are you using? I didn't get the error in V9.0.1)

Comment: I feel a little bit ashamed of myself since I could not fix this simple error. The code works well now. I will increase value of n and let you know the results. I would like to say "thank you" again for all your effort and time on my concern. I hope you have a wonderful day. Sincerely,

Comment: @user16023 You're welcome. And I did have a wonderful day, thank you. :)

Comment: You are very welcome. I tried the code with different values of n. Even though it takes time, the plots look very nice.
Now, I would like to change the search range. For instance, x={-32,1} and y={0,4000}. I edited the code as following :
   n = 20;
   seeds = findSeeds[myHN[n, x + I y], {x, -32, 1}, {y, 0, 4000}, 
    PlotPoints -> 25, 
    MeshFunctions -> {myHNReImCx[n][#1, #2] &, 
      myHNReImCy[n][#1, #2] &}]; // AbsoluteTiming
      allfoundzeros = 
      Quiet@myFRC[myHN[n, z], {z, -32, 1 + 4000 I}, 
       seeds.{1, I}]; // AbsoluteTiming

Comment: uniqueszeros = #[[First@Ordering[Abs@myHN[n, #]]]] & /@ 
    findclusters[allfoundzeros, 10.^-6]; // AbsoluteTiming
zeros = Pick[uniqueszeros, 
    With[{zz = Developer`ToPackedArray@N@uniqueszeros}, 
     UnitStep[(#1 - (-32)) (1 - #1) (#2) (4000 - #2)] &[Re[zz], 
      Im[zz], 1]], 1]; // AbsoluteTiming
Length[zeros]
zeroplot = 
 Graphics[{PointSize[0.0035], Red, 
   Point@Transpose@{Re[zeros], Im[zeros]}}, 
  PlotRange -> {{-32, 1}, {0, 4000}}, AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> True]

Comment: And it has the following warning:
FindRoot::streg: The starting point {-32.340206185567012653336860239505767822265625000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000+1851.395818871414348905091173946857452392578125000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 I} is not in the search region {{-32.34020618556701030927835051546391752577319587628865979381443298969072164948453608247422680412371134-<<156>> I},{<<154>>+<<158>> I}}.
Could you give me some comments? Thank you so much.

Comment: @user16023 What seems to be happening is that `ContourPlot` is finding a seed nearly on the boundary, so that the round-off error moves the seed to outside the boundary and `FindRoot` complains.  You could extend the boundaries for `FindRoot` a little more with `z1 = Re[a - (b - a)/96] + Im[a - (b - a)/97] I; z2 = Re[b + (b - a)/102] + Im[b + (b - a)/101] I;` in `myFRC`.  Or you could test the starting point in the `FindRoot` call and either constrain it to the search region or drop it.

Comment: You mentioned that "The keyword All must not be recognized by Nearest until V10". What does V10 mean?

Comment: @user16023 V = "Version".  (Version 10 has just come out.)

Comment: Using your suggestion, I can extend the boundaries of *FindRoot*, from x={-31,1} to x={-32,1}, but I lost some zeros with n=200.
I am trying *"z1 = Re[a - (b - a)/96.999] + Im[a - (b - a)/97.999] I; z2 = Re[b + (b - a)/102.999] + Im[b + (b - a)/101.999] I;* to see how many zeros lost.