# Finding closest point to implicitly defined curve

Tags: equation-solving, implicit

I'm facing the following problem: Given an implicit curve given by $f(x,y)=0$ and an initial guess $(x_0,y_0)$ which is hopefully close to the curve, I want to find the point $(x,y)$ on the curve which is closest to $(x_0,y_0)$.

**My attempt:**

I thought of using FindRoot with the equation repeated twice, i.e.

```
FindRoot[{f[x,y],f[x,y]},{{x,x0},{y,y0}}]
```

But this fails spectacularly with $f(x,y)=y-x^2$ and initial points $(0,y_0)$ with $y_0$ large.

Is there a good way to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: `NMinimize[{EuclideanDistance[{x, y}, {x0, y0}], f[x, y] == 0}, {x, y}]`?

Comment: "closest" - that kind of screams for the use of `Minimize[]`, no?

Comment: Thanks guys. You can close the question now.

Comment: Better yet, why not answer your own question instead, so you can share what you've learned?

Comment: It might be better to minimize an EuclideanDistance square (a square of the euclidean norm instead of the norm.)

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34204/finding-a-point-from-a-set-of-contours-such-that-it-is-nearest-to-a-given-point

Answer (score 12, accepted):

RegionNearest will do this automatically for many cases, including $y-x^2=0$:

```
RegionNearest[ImplicitRegion[y - x^2 == 0, {x, y}], {0, y0}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]